# Conditional powerlevel9k prompt

Tags: terminal, zsh, prompt, oh-my-zsh

I want to de-activate my right prompt when the tmux terminal pane gets small. Is there an easy way to conditionally render the RPROMPT variable based on screen width?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
RPROMPT='%-50(l|long prompt|short prompt)'
```

For the `long prompt` to be used when the terminal is at least 50 columns wide, and the `short prompt` otherwise.

See [*Conditional Substrings in Prompts* in the manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Conditional-Substrings-in-Prompts) for details and more options.